# Why does ufw don't work but firewall-cmd work on port opening?

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ufw, https

I've enabled some ports (80, 443) in `sudo ufw allow 80/tcp` & `sudo ufw allow 443/tcp`.

But those ports are still blocked.

Few days ago, I added permanent zone using `sudo firewall-cmd --add-port 2224/tcp --permanent` & `sudo firewall-cmd --reload`. This means 2224 port is only opened.

But what does **ufw** mean. Why allowing port using **ufw** doesn't work? It only worked when allowed from `firewall-cmd`.

Comment: Have you tried running `ufw reset` and then trying this again? Also, can you post the output of `iptables -S` and `ufw status numbered`? This would help us better assist you with your question.

Comment: @Chev_603 I didn't. But what I did was tried ufw disable and enabling it again, resetting didn't work either. At later I unblocked port using `sudo firewall-cmd --add-port 80/tcp --permanent` & `sudo firewall-cmd --add-port 443/tcp --permanent`. Later it worked nicely.